# CSS hover not changing colour of text

Tags: css, hover

my css hover is not working.
The code is from a wordpress theme and I think it's using bootstrap, but I'm not sure as I'm a quite new to coding.

the html is (using 'inspect' in Google Chrome):

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-even">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionname651" href="#collapse6510">
      <h5>
        <i class="icon-minus kt-icon-minus primary-color"></i>
        <i class="icon-plus kt-icon-plus"></i>
          Ear Wax Removal
      </h5>
    </a>
  </div>
```

etc...

The above code is part of an 'accordion' menu so that when each 'panel' is clicked there is a drop down of the content in that panel

What I want to do is that when a user hovers on the panel heading the background colour changes BUT so does the colour of the text from black to white.

The current css is:

```
.panel-heading{
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  background: #c9c9c9;
}
```

but although this changes the colour of the background for the panel heading it does nothing to the colour of the text on the heading.

I suspect the answer is going to be pretty simple but I can't work out why it's not working

Thanks in advance for anyone that answers

Comment: There's no text in `.panel-heading`. It's inside an `<h5>` tag. Try `.panel-heading:hover h5`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be easy enough for you guys. the code above worked. By changing it to:
.panel-heading:hover h5
it worked just fine.
Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```css
.panel-heading{
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  background: #c9c9c9;
}
.panel-heading a:hover {
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default panel-even">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionname651" href="#collapse6510">
      <h5>
        <i class="icon-minus kt-icon-minus primary-color"></i>
        <i class="icon-plus kt-icon-plus"></i>
          Ear Wax Removal
      </h5>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the `!important;`.

```
.panel-heading{
  background: #d5d5d5 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
  color: #fdfdfd !important;
  background: #c9c9c9 !important;
}
```